# Add a URL in a fields validation error without complicating the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, design-patterns

One of my model validations in Rails is to ensure an event doesn't overlap with another. I do this by comparing dates on records that already exist.

Where there is an overlap detected, I show a validation error:

> Overlaps with event: ABC Conference --- 1 Jun - 17 Jun

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  validate :prevent_overlaps

  private

  def prevent_overlaps
    # ... detect overlap here
    if overlap.present?
      errors.add :start_date, "Overlaps with event: #{overlap_event.title} --- #{overlap_event.start_date} - #{overlap_event.end_date}"
    end
  end
end
```

Typically, in this use-case, the error will need to be resolved by editing the existing event, not this new one, so I'd like to add a link to the validation message so a user can just click it to go to that event where the overlap exists.

**Is there a Rails pattern for adding a link to that validation?**

Adding link helpers to the model doesn't seem right, but is there any other way that is a better practice while following MVC separation of concerns?

Should this be constructed a different way so the view can add the link as needed itself?

Of course it would be nice to just write this in the model:

```
errors.add :start_date, 
  "Overlaps with event: " + 
  link_to("#{overlap_event.title} --- #{overlap_event.start_date} - #{overlap_event.end_date}", edit_event_path(overlap))`
```

Answer (score 0):

After validation, the redirection will happen in the controller rather than the model.

Something like this:

```
if @event.save
  ...do something...
else
  ...if start_date error validatio error exist...
  ...find the other event...
  ...redirect_to other event edit path...
end
```

You need to replace the actual code with those lines with `...`.